# Export "Tag Specific Options" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, settings, export, code-formatting

I'd like to export my "Tag specific Options" (the formatting options) in Visual Studio 2010 so that the other developers in my office can format their code in the exact same way.

I have though about copying the setting folder, but obviously not everyone in my office wants the same VS 2010 settings as myself.

[Screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqtIK.png) included for some clarity.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the Import and Export Settings Wizard to export any of your Visual Studio settings, and then import them onto your co-workers' machines.** "HTML Tag Specific" is one of the options provided in the list of settings that you can choose from to export.

Here's how to export your settings:

1. In Visual Studio, open the "Tools" menu and select "Import and Export Settings".
2. To export the settings on your workstation, choose "Export selected environment settings", and click the "Next" button.
3. Select the specific settings that you want to export. In your case, you probably want to export only the HTML Tag Specific formatting settings, so uncheck the top-level box, then expand "Options", expand "Text Editor" and check the box next to "HTML Tag Specific". Finally, click the "Next" button.
          [image: Export HTML Tag Specific settings]
4. Choose a location to save your exported file, and click the "Finish" button.

Then, just follow the opposite process to import the file you just saved on your co-workers' machines.